# How to customize Media Breakpoints in Nebular

Tags: angular, nebular

I would like to increase the `small` breakpoint size from `400px` to `470px`. However, I have found no way to include this in my custom Nebular theme.

Is this possible? And if yes, how do I achieve this?

Thanks!